# SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message

Tags: java, web-services, soap, netbeans

I want to run a java application which calls a web service. Everything works fine from the netbeans ide, but fails when I run the .jar generated. What could be the problem?
How can I check the content type that the error is pointing at?

the error says: "**SEVERE: SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message. com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.MessageImpl identifyContentType**"

EDIT
I am realizing that the problem could be originated by the fact that the web service that Im consuming uses a custom data type, but I have no idea where to look. 
Please help

Answer (score 2):

Your question lacks the details that would help identify your problem (like, what web container are you using, some source code, etc) but I've encountered and resolved this same problem. I'm using Tomcat with Eclipse and apparently, the problem occurs because for some reason, **Tomcat can't find some JARs even though I have specified them in my build path**. The resolution is to put the JARs in the actual lib directory of Tomcat instead of in some project-specific location. ([See this same case with log4j.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11188565/777225))

What happens is this missing JAR causes the servlet to produce an internal server error when called. Tomcat generates an error page---which is of type "text/html"---and sends it back to client. So, client reads "text/html" instead of the expected "text/xml".

For a test [this SOAP tutorial](http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=228) produces the specified error due to `jaxm-api.jar` but can be fixed with the solution I described above. I have verified this with Tomcat 7.

> How can I check the content type that the error is pointing at?

A bit difficult to answer without some code. But if you are using `javax.xml.soap.SOAPPart`, it has methods to check the headers of the SOAP transaction. [Check the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPPart.html). Shame it does not override `toString()`. But personally, I did not arrive at this answer with Java debug methods but via looking at TCP dumps.

Comment: +1 because of the explanation of the error itself; in my case, it was the content-type the problem (instead of application/xml it should be text/xml)