# Error Axis2 WebService AxisServlet

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have a problem with an Axis2 Web Service it was working but then i get this exception and I do not know what the error was at first, the WS runs about 100 times every day at 3am - 6am

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [AxisServlet] in context with path 
[/ConsultasDomiciliacion] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation
at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:159)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.error(Log4JLogger.java:257)
at org.apache.axis2.util.OnDemandLogger.error(OnDemandLogger.java:90)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:210)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

Comment: Maybe a problem with Log4J library in the app server's classpath. Did you have a look at [Tomcat 7 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/spi/ThrowableInformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872510/tomcat-7-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-log4j-spi-throwableinforma) already?

Comment: log4j is ok, and i dont get the error in dev, in dev env works, its only in prod. i read It is not problem for log4j and tomcat. It will throw exception because some of mycode run error in webapp init. Maybe xml or config is error.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an extra Log4J jar in the production environment? `ThrowableInformation` was added in v. 1.2.16, so if there happens to be an older version of the jar around, that could cause this problem.

Comment: i don't think so, because was working, the WebService works the first time but the next day at 3am i got the error, but in my proyect i have log4j v. 1.2.15